# ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i'm trying to display the data items retrieved from database in a list view but it is showing this error i don't know why..

Main activity.java

```
package com.example.roopanrajesh.myapplication;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase es;
    Cursor cr;
    //  ArrayList<String>dutylist=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    String[] dutylist = new String[100];
    int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        es = openOrCreateDatabase("es", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        es.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS duty (name VARCHAR,date VARCHAR,roomno VARCHAR,slot VARCHAR);");
        //es.execSQL("INSERT INTO duty values( 'binupk','8-6-2017','N203','AN')");
        //es.execSQL("INSERT INTO duty values( 'jisharc','9-6-2017','N201','FN')");
        //es.execSQL("INSERT INTO duty values( 'subbulekshmis','10-6-2017','N204','AN')");
        //es.execSQL("INSERT INTO duty values( 'veenag','8-6-2017','N101','AN')");
        //es.execSQL("INSERT INTO duty values( 'rahulvarma','9-6-2017','S103','AN')");
        cr=es.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM duty",null);
        cr.moveToFirst();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + cr.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(cr.getCount()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else{
            do
            {
                dutylist[i]=cr.getString(1)+"     "+cr.getString(2)+"     "+cr.getString(3);
                i++;
            }
            while(cr.moveToNext());
        }
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+dutylist[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,0,dutylist);
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

output on logcat

```
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime: Exception
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.roopanrajesh.myapplication, PID: 9144
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1924)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1121)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1303)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1008)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5717)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5127)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5131) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2295) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16653) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1924) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1121) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1303) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1008) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5717) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5127) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
05-08 13:49:26.442 9144-9144/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-08 13:49:26.452 9144-9144/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9144 SIG: 9
```

please help me...
thank you advance!

Comment: how to use that

Comment: that error has gone now it s showing null pointer exception on adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dutylist);

Comment: use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, not `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: how to use simplecursoradapter for this

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: i didnt try anything...what change should i do to the above code to use simplecursoradapter

Comment: just create it: `new SimpleCursorAdapter(...)`, thats all

Comment: What are the parameters

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Comment: please help with the modified working version of this program....and put it as an answer

Comment: i dont see anywhere that you are using `SimpleCursorAdapter` in your modified code

Comment: i didnt modify the code..actually i dont know.....please help me with working program code ..i have to submit this assignment tommorow

Comment: were you googling about `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: yeaah..all were using db helper class and stuff but i dont have that this program is simple just stuck with this error..please provide me with the modified working program pleas  beg you

Comment: `SCA` needs a `Cursor`, the same `Cursor` you are getting using `es.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM duty",null);` - no need for any db helper class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,0,dutylist);`

with this

`adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0,dutylist);`

Answer (score 0):

simply :-

adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,dutylist);